# Post-variables only passed, when action="" is empty

Tags: php, post, action

In a php-script i have a form, method is post, action-attribute is empty, which is working so far. but when i add a value into the action-atribute, like so:

```
 action="index.php?id=9&get-id=5"
```

the whole post-array is empty after submitting.

Someone has any idea what this could be about?

Thanx in advance, Jayden

edit: here is an Example:

```
 $form = '<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?id=9&get-id=5">
                         <input type="text" name="name1" value="">
                         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
                    </form>';
```

The form is displayed in a tab in a js-tabmenu, which opens also by get-parameters, in each tab is a form and after submitting the get-param is needed to display the right tab with the right form.

Comment: Do you use `$_POST` to access the POST variables? Show us some of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: use........................            $_REQUEST

Comment: @zod thank you very much, i think it is working with $_REQUEST, gonna google that later to learn more about it. thanx bro...

Comment: sorry, that chears was too early, actually its still not working... dont understand this. the script is still executed, but why not with the post-vars? there are still other get-parameter in the url, but only if i add some to action, it is not working. so do i have to do a redirect here or is there another way? sometimes this building websites etc stuff is an annoying thing to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `$_REQUEST`

which is collection of $_GET and $_POST

Answer (score 2):

You should not use both GET and POST in a request.

You must only use post, therefore the two variables 'id' and 'get-id' should be in the form (use hidden fields)

edit:

try changing your code to:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="index.php?id=9&get-id=5">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9">
    <input type="hidden" name="get-id" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="name1" value="">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

then if you :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

at the top of the index.php page you should be able to see what is going on.

Also - just to check are there any redirects in your code, ie does index.php then redirect somewhere else as that would cause the $_POST to get lost

Comment: really? whats the use of the action-attribute then anyway?!

Comment: the action attribute is to specify the URL to where it sends the form, you should be using `action="index.php"`

Comment: Nah, that is not true. Give it a try!

Comment: I would put all the data into the form, then you can just use the post and shouldn't have any issues - if you post more code it'll be easier to figure out

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access id or get-id from your script: Those were appended to the url, even if you submit that form via post. Therefore you will find their values in $_GET, as usual. Only the values of `<input>` fields (and textarea etc., simply: all form elements) are in $_POST.